# Ansible ios_config stuck on MOTD

Tags: ansible

I have a simple playbook that is getting hung up on the MOTD banner causing the error message: command timeout triggered.

When initially logging in, "--MORE--" is displayed from the MOTD.

I've attempted to use the expect module before the ios_config to bypass the MOTD to no avial:

```
- name: Continue After MOTD
  expect:
    command: "echo 'q\n'"
    responses: 
      prompt: "*#"
```

Is there anything that can be done to get send a 'q' key (quit) to begin displaying the prompt to start the ios_config task?

This seems like an easy problem to solve but so far it's been extremely difficult!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following and working fine for me.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Continue After MOTD
      expect:
        command: "echo q | more <file1>"
        responses:
         prompt: "*#"
```

Comment: No change. I'm stuck with the terminal's last line displaying --MORE--

Comment: Could you please share task which will invoke MOTD